# How CMS decides when to collect SoftReferences?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot, soft-references

I wrote a memory sensitive cache using soft references.

At first it worked well, but after a few days, memory pressure went high, then suddenly dropped.

Well, this is expected, I want to the cache to hold data as long as possible but not so long to cause out-of-memory. Kind of graceful degradation.

But from then, it didn't work so well. I find somehow it has become dropping data more aggressively.

The question is, does the JVM somehow tune itself adaptively and decides to drop SoftReference more aggressively?

Comment: I would say it's precise behaviour shouldn't be relied upon as different versions at different times can behave differently. One approach I take is to cache data off heap so it's isolated from the momentary behaviour of the application.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well, I did write an off-heap version (in fact it was designed from the beginning in a way that I could easily change it into an off-heap version). I am just curious. I don't understand why there seems a "phase change".